# How to add a set every time to a set in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I tried to write a program that add a different set to a set every time, so I tried this:

```
for i in range (5):
    Set = set()
    Set.update(set(str(i)))
```

But unfortunetly I got this result when I `print (Set)`: `{'1', '4', '2', '0', '3'}` While I was expecting `{{'1'}, {'4'}, {'2'}, {'0'}, {'3'}}`. Because the result I got is supposed to be the output if the last line was `Set.add(str(i))` not `Set.add(set(str(i)))`.
So why and how to write a code that do this purpose ?!

NOTE: I edited this upon the advice I appreciate of @martineau. If this is a bad act then please cancel the edit and get back my old question instead of downvoting this question again.

Comment: “add an empty set to a set multiple times,” a set can only contain unique items. Maybe you want a `list` instead?

Comment: What is your real problem? I think that `add an empty set to a set multiple times` is not really what you want to do, because it is impossible for two reasons: 1) set is unhashable 2) set can contain only one empty `frozenset` (closest equivalent to set).

Comment: What if I need to add a different element every time in a loop like:
```for i in range (5): Set = set() Set.add(set(str(i)))```

Comment: If you need to add a different element each time, you need to ask THAT question.

Comment: @mhhollomon I wanted to simplify it. I thought that it is the same thing !!!

Comment: Your rules here are so strict I don't know how I could survive without being blocked permanently !! @mhhollomon

Comment: Sorry you feel that way. I know it can get nasty. But one bad post won't get you banned. The main problem is that the question you asked is not really the problem you are trying to solve. You have a bigger issue with how you defined your data structure. Remember also, this site's purpose is as an archive to help OTHER people in the *future* to find answers to questions. So a down vote may only reflect that people don't think this is a good way to ask the question. Not really a value judgement on you personally.

Comment: @mhhollomon
Ok no problem but I think that you gave good answers to my question so if someone else has the same question as me then he can simply get the answer from this question while I'm gonna ask another question for my issue. Alternatively if I get banned forever then there will be no more questions from me or from people who get banned like me to enrich this site !!

Comment: It's not your fault, but this sounds like a classic case of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Suggest you ask another that includes at least the details of _why_ you want to do this (or how doing so will help you do something else).

Comment: Thanks @martineau
Yeah I'm gonna ask another question but I got blocked for 3 days now. So this will be after 96 hours 

Comment: Roofnos: Well, in that case perhaps you could [edit] this question and add the missing information.

Comment: @martineau
I tried to do like this before and I got downvoted for doing it 

Comment: add an empty string instead?  `myset = { str(i) if i > 0 else "" for i in range(5)}` ==> `{'', '3', '1', '2', '4'}

 `

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner
I hope you look at my question again after editing. It is about adding sets to a set not adding strings to a set.

Comment: You are pythonically unable to add sets into sets. It is impossible. You can add frozensets - wich are the immuteable type sets. Simply add a frozenset (empty) or (with string as single element) to your set: `myset = { frozenset([str(i)]) if i > 0 else frozenset([""]) for i in range(5)}` ==> `{frozenset({'4'}), frozenset({'1'}), frozenset({'2'}), frozenset({'3'}), frozenset({''})}`

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner I don't know why when I tried to do it with my code be replacing `set` with `frozenset` nothing changed and I got the same result !! I don't know how to write it in one code but add a pre of 'frozen' before 'set' in the last line and see the result !! I still having a set without elements as frozensets !!

Comment: As martineau said, you have an XY problem. When the system permits you to ask a new question you should ask about your real problem, with a [mcve]. It sounds like you need a different data structure, since you cannot have a set of modifiable sets. You may also need a different algorithm to complement the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

`set` objects themselves are mutable, so they cannot be hashed (items must be hashable to be able to add them into sets). OTOH, if you don't intend on modifying the empty set, you can instantiate a `frozenset` object instead:

```
Set = set()
Set.add(frozenset())

# Set
{frozenset()}
```

A `frozenset` works exactly as a set, except that it cannot be modified once it is created.

Comment: I'm gonna need to modify the empty sets. Is there any other way?!!

Comment: @Roofnos yes. Rethink your data structure.

Comment: @PM2Ring that's right, thanks!